# No funciona el campo required en un formulario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario donde uso boostrap y jquery.

Tengo los campos **input text** como **required**, pero cuando hago pulso en el botón de "enviar" no me marca que son campos requeridos y me deja hacer el envío:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Peso:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control" placeholder="peso" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Altura:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control" placeholder="height" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Luego en el botón submit hago esto

```
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){


    $('#alert-ok').css('display', 'none');
    $('#error-list').css('display', 'none');

    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿El envío del formulario lo haces mediante el formulario o mediante código (XHR)? Estás capturando el evento clic del botón, no el envío del formulario, por lo que desaparecen los IDs `#alert-ok` y `#alert-list` cuando pulsas el botón independientemente de si el formulario es válido o no.

Comment: Lo más probable es que sea el `e.preventDefault();` que estás usando para el botón de submit. Ahora, mi pregunta es ¿Para que lo estás usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca el html de tu boton, recuerda que debe ser el `type="submit"` y no  de tipo `button` ej:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
```

y lo mas importante que tienes que usar en tu script lo siguiente:

```
 $("form").submit(function(e)
 {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#alert-ok').css('display', 'none');
     $('#error-list').css('display', 'none'); 
 });
```

como usas jQuery el metodo de ejecucion debe ser submit en vez de click.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si me funcionó. 1000 gracias

Comment: @ilernet, si contestaras a los comentarios te ayudaríamos podríamos ayudarte mejor. Apenas tres minutos después de hacer tu pregunta te hice un comentario explicando el motivo de esta solución.

Answer (score -2):

el ejemplo que pusiste ¿esta dentro del form? es que yo lo puse de la siguiente manera

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Peso:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control" placeholder="peso" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Altura:</strong>
                    <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control" placeholder="height" required>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

y por ejemplo cuando intento enviar los campos vacíos me marca que son  requeridos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]